# Why can't I save my custom CRS?

Tags: qgis

I am unable to create custom CRSes in QGIS. The 'save' button doesn't seem to have any effect. My best guess is that I don't have permission to save in the folder or database where custom CRSes go. I have looked at the screenshots of other users who are having trouble with this, and I usually see "1 of 1" in the custom CRS browser. On my system, I see "* of 0" instead

[image]

Any assistance appreciated.

QGIS version: 1.8.0

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem on my own. After some investigation, I found that the ~/.qgis folder was owned by root and had permissions 644. With these permissions, the qgis.db cannot be created when QGIS runs, and settings cannot be saved. There are two ways to fix this problem.

1. Delete the ~/.qgis folder. It will automatically be recreated when you run QGIS, but with you as owner and permissions 776.
2. Manually modify the ~/.qgis folder using the chown, chgrp, and chmod commands so that you are the owner and permissions are 776.

Based on issue ticket #914, this problem has been fixed in the source:
http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo/ticket/914