# QGIS custom CRS won't save

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I can define a custom CRS in QGIS (v2.18.13, Windows 8) and conversion works fine and no error is reported when I hit OK.

proj4 is +proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

[image: Custom CRS dialogue]

But when I go to use this CRS, there are no user-defined projections in the list.

[image: Change CRS]

A similar issue was raised [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34801/why-cant-i-save-my-custom-crs) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240306/cant-define-custom-crs-in-qgis), but neither answer fixed my problem. May be a permissions issue, as the problem is not limited to the specific proj4 that I use, but I've enabled write access on all QGIS folder, still with no luck.

I'm experienced with GIS applications, but new to QGIS.

Comment: It works for me with QGIS 2.18.13. Menu for User defined CRS shows the new CRS as USER:100000 and all the parameters are there.

Comment: Did you click on the plus button before OK?

Comment: Oh snap! Thanks @underdark. This was clearly not the intuitive order of operations to me! Works now. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in QGIS 3.10.0, but the plus button trick doesn't help.

Comment: Same here. Very annoying..! (QGIS 3.10.1-A Coruña)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested above, you need to hit the plus sign **after** entering the proj4 information (not **before**). This was not at all intuitive to me, so I'll leave this (somewhat humbling) answer up here for others, in case I'm not the only outlier.

Comment: This should be marked as a fully valid answer!

Comment: @Taras It surely should. Done!