# QGIS 3.4 - Can't Save Custom Projection

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am having the same issue on QGIS 3.10 or the long term release, 3.4

If I go to Settings > Custom Projection and add a name and parameters, the "OK" button does nothing.

I have tried clicking the plus button before and after adding the name and parameters, it makes no difference.

I have read similar questions:

- [QGIS custom CRS won't save](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257377)
- [Why can't I save my custom CRS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34801)
- [Can't define Custom CRS in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240306)

but none of their answers work for me.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling different versions of QGIS, and have tried granting write permissions to folders within the QGIS directory.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! The custom projection seems to be already added. You can see it in the list.