Adding NTV2 transformation for Bavaria to QGIS
I have a .gsb file for the conversion but even after a lot of searches I am not sure about what to do with it or how to incorporate it into QGIS, I tried adding it to proj.db but I don't know about the parameters to enter.
https://www.ldbv.bayern.de/vermessung/utm_umstellung/trans_geofach.html
The NTV is found in the link above. The CRS I want to transform from is 31468 and the target CRS is 25832.
I also tried ogr2ogr using gdal in Python using:
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp Testpunkte_Echtumstellung.shp -s_srs EPSG:31468 -t_srs EPSG:25832 -ct ntv2_bayern.gsb

but it also fails.

Maybe my answer for BW can assist you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/420951/99589. I execute Datum Transformations from EPSG:31467 to EPSG:25832.
